# Checking SPF for outgoing mails

Tags: postfix, spam, spf

Is there any particular reason why I should not perform SPF checks for outgoing mails?

I was reading on some articles that *"you should not perform SPF checks for outgoing mails"*, why?

I'm doing SPF checks for incoming mails and it saves me from lot of spam, but sometimes I get some spam sent from my shared hosting servers, could be outgoing SPF checks valid to block some spam?

Comment: You didn't even link to those articles?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF

Comment: Aww found the missing piece: http://www.openspf.org/Best_Practices/Outbound my bad

Answer (score 1):

Outgoing spf checks won't give you any advantage. if you have configured your own server and dns correctly they will always pass anyway, so performing them is only a waste of your resources.

Comment: For your own mail, this is true. Not in his case, where he's hosting other people's mail service.

Comment: Yep, but i have a shared hosting environment and the outdated joomcrap is getting exploited everyday to send huge amount of spam from my servers...

Comment: in that case i would rather create a whitelist of domains which are allowed to send mails out. but outgoing spf checks could also be one possible solution.